# NewBee! Want to import Excel sheet data to DB table via SSIS(Visual Studio) Script task with C#

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I want to import Excel Data of Table 2 from 13th row.
And I need to use header column. So that it can import the data in future if
column name or row name changes.

I'm very new to this and I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed with this.
[image]

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                               
  int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
  int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
  string eachVal = "";

 for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
   {
 string queryString = "INSERT INTO [Table_Name] ( [Col1],[Col2], [Col3])values ";
    queryString += "(";
    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
     {
     eachVal = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim();
     queryString += "'" + eachVal + "',";
                                   
      }
        queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1); 
       queryString += ")";
        runQuery(queryString);  
                                }
```

Comment: A few suggestions... 1) Add what you want your result to look like. 2) I suggest using OleDB connection so you can do something like "Select * from [Sheet1$A13:F]"

Comment: Hi @KeithL, Thanks, I trying OleDB connection toon now. As I saw many one suggesting that.